# How to check before actions the xpath available or not?

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, xpath

I want to check xpath available or not. But I don't want to ignore any error.

I want to do like this...

if `driver.find_element_by_xpath("your xpath"):`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("your xpath").click()
```

But it's not working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use elements it will work. Like...

```
if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("your xpath"):
driver.find_element_by_xpath("your xpath").click()
```

It will work.

Comment: Aww it's working! Thank you very much @Jawad